# Responsive menu header logo hidden behind menu options - CSS

Tags: html, css

I found this pretty cool responsive menu on the Codepen website:
https://codepen.io/SergioDaroca/pen/bgKPqY

But when I've added it to my site, The header title "Rhino" is centralised behind the menu options when viewing the full desktop menu. It works ok for the hamburger menu. Here you can see it not working on my site:
https://bozzaradio.co.uk/default.aspx

Is there  way I can adjust the code to fix this? I've tried changing position:relative etc but my CSS knowledge isn't that great.

```
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <header class="header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a class="nlogo" href="https://www.savetherhino.org" title=" font-family: Lato, sans-serif">RHINO</a>
        <nav><!-- MAIN MENU <div class="navicon">&#9776;</div> <div class="navicon">?</div> -->
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu-input-checkbox" role="button">
            <label for="show-menu-input-checkbox" id="main-menu-toggler" class="flex-container flex-vcenter flex-hcenter"><div id="main-menu-toggler-icon" class="flex-grow"></div></label>
            <ul class="mainMenu accordion" id="mainMenu"><li><a 
                 href="https://bozzaradio.co.uk/default.aspx" >Home</a></li><li><a 
                 href="https://bozzaradio.co.uk/djs.aspx" >DJ's</a></li><li><a 
                 href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams" target="_blank">Shedule</a></li><li><a 
                 href="https://archive.org/details/internetarcade" target="_blank">News</a></li><li><a 
                 href="https://archive.org/details/prelinger" target="_blank">Advertise</a></li><li><a 
                 href="https://archive.org/details/prelinger" target="_blank">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
/* 
  RESETS
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;height:100%;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}
body{
  width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;
  border:1px dotted gray;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
header ul, menu, dir {
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
a{text-decoration:none;color:rgba(255,102,0,1);}

/* 
  LAYOUT
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
:root{
    --maxSiteWidth:1080px;
}
main{
  margin: 90px auto;padding:1em;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    height: 80px;
    border-bottom: rgba(44,44,44,.6) 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    height:80px;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    font-size:42px;display:block;text-align:center;align-items:center;justify- 
content:center;margin:14px auto;
}

/*  
   MAIN MENU MOBILE FIRST
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
nav{flex:1 auto;}
.mainMenu{
  position: fixed;top:0;left: 0;right: 0;
  margin:80px auto 0 auto;
    height:90%;/**hack for opera mini**/
    height:calc(100% - 79px);
  width:100%;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  align-content:stretch;
  display:none;
}
.mainMenu a{
  flex:1;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:26px;
  display:flex;
  background:transparent;
}
.mainMenu>li {
    flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(22,22,22,.3);
  background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

/*  
  MAIN MENU TOGGLE BUTTON
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/*Hide checkbox*/
#show-menu-input-checkbox{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
#show-menu-input-checkbox:checked ~ .mainMenu{
    display: flex;
}
#main-menu-toggler {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  padding:24px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;align-items:center;
}
#main-menu-toggler-icon:after,
#main-menu-toggler-icon:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: -9px;
}
#main-menu-toggler-icon:after{
top: 9px;
}
#main-menu-toggler-icon {
position: relative;
display: block;
}
#main-menu-toggler-icon,
#main-menu-toggler-icon:after,
#main-menu-toggler-icon:before {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color:rgba(22,22,22,1);
transition: all 0.3s;
backface-visibility: hidden;
border-radius: 2px;
}
/* on menu activation */
#show-menu-input-checkbox:checked ~ #main-menu-toggler>#main-menu-toggler-icon {
background-color: transparent;
}
#show-menu-input-checkbox:checked ~ #main-menu-toggler>#main-menu-toggler-icon:before {
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
#show-menu-input-checkbox:checked ~ #main-menu-toggler>#main-menu-toggler-icon:after {
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}

/*
  MAIN MENU ON WIDE SCREENS
/*----------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    header,.mainMenu,nav,main,article,footer{max-width:var(--maxSiteWidth);}
    /**HIDE THE MENU TOGGLER**/
    #main-menu-toggler{display:none;}
    /**APPLY HORIZONTAL BAR STYLING TO THE MAIN MENU**/
    .mainMenu{
    position: initial;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height:80px;
    margin-top:0;
  }
    .mainMenu>li {
    flex:1 0 auto;
    border-bottom:none;
    background:transparent;
    align-items:initial;
  }
    .mainMenu a{
    font-size:22px;
    width:auto;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-left:16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. I had another 'nav' in the CSS conflicting with it.